Specify lifetime of async response handler without requiring 'static or HRTBs
I have a library struct that represents a host using multi-threading to asynchronously communicate with an NCP. Since the project is rather complex, I stripped it down to an MRE:
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::future::Future;
use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Receiver, Sender};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::thread::{spawn, JoinHandle};

pub struct Host {
    thread: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    command: Sender<Command>,
}

impl Host {
    pub fn spawn() -> Self {
        let (command_sender, command_receiver) = channel();
        let processor = Processor::new(command_receiver);
        Self {
            thread: Some(spawn(|| processor.run())),
            command: command_sender,
        }
    }

    pub async fn communicate<T>(&self, payload: &[u8]) -> Result<T::Result, T::Error>
    where
        T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send,
    {
        let response = T::default();
        let clone = Arc::new(response.clone());
        self.command
            .send(Command::new(Arc::from(payload), clone))
            .map_err(|_| Error::Terminated)?;
        response.await
    }
}

impl Drop for Host {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        if let Some(handle) = self.thread.take() {
            handle.join().unwrap();
        }
    }
}

struct Processor {
    sender: Receiver<Command>,
}

impl Processor {
    pub const fn new(sender: Receiver<Command>) -> Self {
        Self { sender }
    }

    pub fn run(self) {
        loop {
            println!("{:?}", self.sender.recv().unwrap());
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum HandleResult {
    Completed,
    Continue,
    Failed,
    Reject,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Event<'data> {
    TransmissionCompleted,
    DataReceived(Result<&'data [u8], Error>),
}

pub trait Handler: Debug + Send + Sync {
    fn handle(&self, event: Event) -> HandleResult;
    fn abort(&self, error: Error);
    fn wake(&self);
}

pub trait Response: Future<Output = Result<Self::Result, Self::Error>> + Handler
where
    Self::Error: From<Error>,
{
    type Result;
    type Error;
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Command {
    pub(crate) payload: Arc<[u8]>,
    pub(crate) handler: Arc<dyn Handler>,
}

impl Command {
    #[must_use]
    pub const fn new(payload: Arc<[u8]>, handler: Arc<dyn Handler>) -> Self {
        Self { payload, handler }
    }
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    Terminated,
}

impl Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Terminated => write!(f, "lorem ipsum"),
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {}

The problem is the lifetime bound on T in communicate():
error[E0310]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:30:52
   |
30 |             .send(Command::new(Arc::from(payload), clone))
   |                                                    ^^^^^
   |                                                    |
   |                                                    the parameter type `T` must be valid for the static lifetime...
   |                                                    ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
25 |         T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send + 'static,
   |                                                     +++++++++

error[E0311]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:30:52
   |
23 |     pub async fn communicate<T>(&self, payload: &[u8]) -> Result<T::Result, T::Error>
   |                                 ----- the parameter type `T` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined here...
...
30 |             .send(Command::new(Arc::from(payload), clone))
   |                                                    ^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
23 ~     pub async fn communicate<'a, T>(&'a self, payload: &[u8]) -> Result<T::Result, T::Error>
24 |     where
25 ~         T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send + 'a,
   |

error[E0311]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:30:52
   |
23 |     pub async fn communicate<T>(&self, payload: &[u8]) -> Result<T::Result, T::Error>
   |                                                 ----- the parameter type `T` must be valid for the anonymous lifetime defined here...
...
30 |             .send(Command::new(Arc::from(payload), clone))
   |                                                    ^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
   |
help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound
   |
23 ~     pub async fn communicate<'a, T>(&self, payload: &'a [u8]) -> Result<T::Result, T::Error>
24 |     where
25 ~         T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send + 'a,
   |

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0310, E0311.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0310`.
error: could not compile `lifetimes` (lib) due to 3 previous errors

I can solve this by either requiring the 'static lifetime:
        T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send + 'static,

or by using higher-rank trait bounds:
        for<'a> T: Clone + Default + Response + Sync + Send + 'a,

My question is two-fold:

Is there a semantic difference between using 'static and the HRTB in the above case, or do both boil down to requiring T for 'static in the end?
Is it possible to introduce some lifetime parameter to the function instead, so that I neither require 'static nor HRTBs? I was unable to specify a non-static lifetime that satisfied the compiler.



In this case, the HRTB does indeed require that T: 'static.  2. The future could complete any time during the lifetime of the thread that was spawned by the Host, so you can only avoid requiring T: 'static if you spawn scoped threads.


Thank you for the clarification and the playground code. I actually played around with scoped threads to no avail. The issue is, that I want to transparently spawn the threads upon Host's creation and tear them down when it's dropped. Is there a way to create scoped threads for the lifetime of Host without passing in the scope to spawn()?

A scoped thread is a thread that is guaranteed to terminate before the scope ends.  You're asking for the ability to drop Host before that.  What if the thread had not completed, e.g. the future was still pending?

Good point. I think I'll keep the current design for now, since in it's intended usage it will last for the entire duration of the program anyways.

T: 'static does not require that values of T live for the lifetime of the entire program, just that they do not contain borrows of any lifetime less than 'static (in this case, in order that a value could be held for the remaining lifetime of the program—not that it necessarily will be).
